# Deleting Section from UITableView works in one direction but not the other

Tags: uitableview

I have looked at the other items on SO, but nothing seems to help. I am trying to delete sections from my tableview. They can be dynamically created by the user.  If I delete them from the bottom up, everything works. But if I delete them from the top down, the second section does not delete and the third section is deleted instead. This continues down the list, and when the second section is all that's left, deleting it results in an index out of range.

I am quite sure that I have deleted the matching section from my data model before I try to delete the section, so I'm not sure what's going wrong. Here's my code for deleting a section:

```
 @objc func deleteButtonTapped(_ sender:UIButton) {

    var sectionToDelete = sender.tag
    print ("Before: \(sections.count)")

    sections.remove(at:sectionToDelete)
    expanded.remove(at:sectionToDelete)

    print ("After: \(sections.count)")

    defaults.set(sections,forKey:"Sections")
    defaults.set(expanded, forKey:"Expanded")

    let indexSet = IndexSet(arrayLiteral: sectionToDelete) // indexSet will be the section I want deleted
    tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer:sectionToDelete),with: .fade)  // out of range



}
```

Any thoughts about where to go from here?

Comment: I suspect your tag values are set once for the original layout and not recalculated after something is deleted.  Try printing `sectionToDelete` and see what you get.

Comment: Correct, when I delete the first section, the new first section's tag (sectionToDelete) is 1 but it should be zero. I'm just not sure how to fix that.

Comment: I don't know how these tags are configured but, if you're using them as a source of data, you obviously need to update them when your section count (or order) changes.